# How to add custom string value in validation schema using Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I have this basic yup validation schema for my react project.

```
const DisplayingErrorMessagesSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  username: Yup.string()
    .min(2, "Too Short!")
    .max(50, "Too Long!")
    .required("Required"),
  email: Yup.string().email("Invalid email").required("Required")
});
```

For username, it currently validates the required property when the username field is an empty string, but to validate even more with multiple default strings like "none", and "admin". How can I validate these default strings also for the username field?

Answer (score 0):

They have [`matches()`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#stringmatchesregex-regex-message-string--function-schema) method that does what you are asking:

```js
username: Yup.string()
  .matches(/(none|default)/, { message: "Username invalid", excludeEmptyString: true })
  .required("Required"),
```